# Solve for $x$ in a defined summation

Tags: summation

I'm looking for the steps in solving for x in this summation:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{12} 83.3(1+x)^i=1,100$$

I know that the solution is $x=0.0145764$, but I need to know how to arrive at the solution. My ultimate goal is to write an equation in excel to solve for x based on inputs $a=83.3$ and $b=1,100$.

Comment: This equation has $12$ solutions, why did you pick this one?

Comment: i have found only two real solutions

Comment: your solution is wrong

Comment: plus $10$ complex solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like an interest rate problem in excel where $x$ is your monthly rate, $83.3$ is a monthly payment, and $12$ is the number of months. If your ultimate goal is an Excel function, here is the solution:

```
=RATE(12,-83.3,0,1100,1)
```

or in your case:

```
=RATE(12,-a,0,b,1)
```